# How to store the value selected from the ui-select2 in scope variable using angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, ui-select2

I need to display values in the dropdown. The values will be retrived from the database for that I have planned to use ui-select2 in angular js.

I can able to get the values from the database through ajax request .

Now I am in need to store the value displayed in the ui-select2 dropdown into the scope variable

For example need to stored the value in $scope.result

Could anyone help me how to store that in scope variable ?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try: `ng-model="result"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method...

```
<ui-select ng-model="address.selected"
             theme="bootstrap"
             ng-disabled="disabled"
             reset-search-input="false"
             style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Enter an address...">{{$select.selected.formatted_address}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="address in addresses track by $index"
             refresh="refreshAddresses($select.search)"
             refresh-delay="0">
      <div ng-bind-html="address.formatted_address | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>



    $scope.address = {};
      $scope.refreshAddresses = function(address) {
        var params = {address: address, sensor: false};
        return $http.get(
          'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
          {params: params}
        ).then(function(response) {
          $scope.addresses = response.data.results
        });
      };
```